# API Gateway URL Path Parameters not passed through

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a subpath parameter `{item}` in an AWS API Gateway resource (`/media/{item}`).

I have created an AWS Service integration `GET` request.

In *URL Path Parameters* I have mapped `item` from `method.request.path.item` and hardwired a `bucket` parameter.

Under *Path override* I've provided `{bucket}/{item}`.

When I make a test call to the path with my key `mykey.png` I get an XML response listing all files in the bucket (not all buckets) and an empty `Method request path: {}` rather than the expected `Method request path: {item=mykey.png}`.

Does anyone have any idea about where I'm falling down?

Comment: have you found a solution? don't hesitate to answer your own question, if so

Comment: Sorry no I didn't. I went down a different route using subdomains for media.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing in a value for my path param which was not properly encoded as a URI component. This caused the method request path to be empty:

```
Method request path: {}
```